# How big of a RTG would you need to power a single home?

Tags: electricity

In the future, under a growing need to slow climate change while also needing to power the billions of homes on Earth, a plan to power every home is put in place. Each home will be installed with a radioisotope thermoelectric generator with Pu-238 as a fuel. RTGs use heat generated by radioactive decay to generate electricity, NASA uses these bad boys to power probes going farther out than Mars

Why Pu-238? it's a good balance between power (estimated half-watt per gram), life span (half-life of 87 years), and safety (you will need a 2.5-25 mm thick sheet of lead wrapped around the cube of plutonium to be safe from radiation)

So, how big would an RTG have to be to power a home?

Comment: Pu-238 is listed as .54W/g (thermal) Then combine with household usage. 100A service is common, which is definitely above peak usage. this suggests 22Kg of Pu-238. Which is well into the W.T.F. territory. Actual mass and volume of the unit? Not worth trying to figure out.

Comment: -1 for failing to Google the average residential electrical service size in any country and for failing to Google the equation for converting voltage and amps to watts, and for failing to Google the size of the current RTG. All of those are trivial Google searches. This isn't a worldbuilding problem. Please remember we are not a free reserach service.

Comment: This year everyone will be learning about proliferation risks, and why there are now worse things that having someone siphoning hydrocarbon fuel out of your tanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 500 W electric power

Assuming that you also employ a battery in order to absorb generated energy from the RTG (as it can't generate less, it's no fission reactor) while there's no consumption and supplement it while there's overconsumption, you can essentially operate values on daily needs. Also note that RTG can be effectively used as a heating device, eliminating the needs of external heating equipment and corresponding energy consumption.

So, let's take an average household energy consumption as reported [here](https://www.utilitybidder.co.uk/compare-business-energy/what-is-an-average-households-energy-usage/) at 10 kWh/day. This consumption is translated into 10000/24 ~= 400 W of generating power (electricity only), assuming 20% losses  in transfer, 500 W. A 500 watt electric power means about 9 kW of thermal power, based on thermal to electric power ratio on [*Curiosity*](https://www.energy.gov/ne/articles/powering-curiosity-multi-mission-radioisotope-thermoelectric-generators), which is enough to supply the household with heating in cold seasons, an alternative heat dumping system (like a PC radiator) can be installed in order to not overheat the house in hot seasons. This heat can probably also be used in cooking, so that the house could spend no energy to that purpose.

About the size - the required 500 W RTG is about the same as the set of three RTGs installed on [*Voyager 1*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHW-RTG). Yet, they were designed to operate at cold junction point temperature of 500C, while on Earth you can achieve much lower temperatures for cold junction point, increasing energy output of energy conversion elements. I think it's safe to assume that with cold junction point at 100C you would need two of these instead of three. Assuming from the photo in that Wiki article, each of them is human-sized, with 4.5 kg Pu-238 inside, so pretty much usable for a house that only uses 10 kWh/day, and this output would last for about 25 years.

Comment: That 500W won't cover peak demand, won't even run a water heater (which, admittedly, might be heated by waste heat from the cold junctions).  A toaster or microwave oven draws much more than 400 W, even if the oven and rangetop can run on waste heat.  Therefor you need a way to store that energy, adding volume and mass (and cost and losses) to the system.  A 400W electrical output system just won't run a home that isn't highly optimized for low peak consumption.

Comment: @ZeissIkon right, but don't you see that I said battery? The RTG+UPS is like a solar-powered home in concept, you have a large battery and energy influx, alternating for solar panels and constant for RTG. These cover peak demands by battery which is then recharged by generation. And, water heater is stuff that's better run by heat, not by electricity if you have an RTG.

Comment: The critical mass of Pu238 is about 10 kg. Three such RTG cover it nicely. Free atomic bombs for Usama bin Ladin's pupils! (Or else be prepared to spend *a lot* of money to ensure the security of the darned things.)

Answer (score 0):

The space RTG units are very expensive. But they were trying to get power for years for as little mass as possible. But something along these lines might be possible.

Conventional nuclear reactors produce some high-grade nuclear waste. This is  stuff that has to be kept cool for some tens of years, re-processed, or disposed of some other way, such as vitrification.

Suppose you had an insulated stove such as an Aga or Raeburn with a small drum of nuclear waste in it. If little heat is being lost, the stove would get hot enough so you could cook or heat water with it. This would provide a lot of the household needs, and possibly provide a bit of electricity, though probably not enough for A/C or a fridge-freezer. You would lease the waste drum from the nuclear power company, and provide the cooling and monitoring for them. The drum might need an external vent to get rid of Radon and any other gases so pressure does not build up.